# Measure expected time to execute any function

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, machine-learning

Often in Machine Learning, training consumes a lot of time and though, this is measurable, but only after the end of training.

Is there some method which can be used to **estimate** the time it might take to complete the training(or generally, any function), something like a `before_call`?

Sure it depends on the machine and more on the inputs but an approximation based on all the IO the algorithm will call, based on simple inputs and then scaled to the size of the actual inputs. Something like this?

*PS - JS, Ruby or any other OO language*
*PPS - I see that in Oracle there is a way, [described here](https://dwbi.org/database/oracle/35-how-to-find-out-expected-time-of-completion-for-an-oracle-query). That is cool. How is it done?*

Answer (score 1):

Let Ci be the complexity of the i'th learning step. Let Pi be the probability that the thing to be learned will be learned at or before the i'th step. Let k be the step where Pk > 0.5.

In this case the complexity, C is

C = sum(Pi, i=1,k)

The problem is that k is difficult to find. In this case it is a good idea to have a stored set of previously learned similar patterns and compute their average step number, which will be the median. If the set is large-enough, it will be pretty accurate.

Pi = the number of instances when things were learned by step i / total number of instances

Answer (score 0):

In case if you did not set any time/number of steps limits (that will be trivial), there is no way to estimate required time **in general**.

For example, neural network training basically is a problem of **global high-dimensional optimization**. In this task your are trying to find such set of parameters to a given loss function, that it will return minimal error. This task belong to **NP-complete** class and is very difficult to solve. Common approach is to randomly change some parameters by a small value in hope that it will improve overall performance. It works great in practice, but required runtime can vary greatly from problem to problem. I would recommend to read about [NP-completness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness), [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) and [optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) in general.